# Sending selected rows(via checkbox) from one gridview to another

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a gridview on one page and I want to send only selected rows from that gridview to another gridview which is one the next page.

Below is the code for selected rows:

```
private void TestCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;enter code here
    var row = dgUsers.Items[0].ToString();
    object item = dgUsers.SelectedItem;
    string ID = (dgUsers.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
    string Name = (dgUsers.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
    Product p1 = new Product();//class of product
    p1.ID = ID;
    p1.Name = Name;
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Product p1 = new Product();
        dg.Items.Add(p1.ID);
        dg.Items.Add(p1.Name);   
    }
}
```

Comment: What language/frameworks do you use, it's not clear on the question

Comment: @benzen Tag says it's wpf, but what page is he referring to?

Comment: Can you post the XAML too?

Comment: Don't you use MVVM or bindings?